# Can't point netbeans to my log4j.xml file

Tags: classpath, java-ee-6, netbeans-7, slf4j, log4j2

I have a webbapp, in which i am using SLF4J and Log4j. Everything works fine except logging mechanish:
When I try to use

```
DOMConfigurator.configure("log4j.xml");
```

I get
 `java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.34\bin\log4j.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:79)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:70)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:161)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:651)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:186)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:772)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:232)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:284)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:208)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator$1.parse(DOMConfigurator.java:749)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:871)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:755)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.configure(DOMConfigurator.java:896)
    at com.dataart.mediaportal.servlet.LoginServlet.service(LoginServlet.java:37)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)`

But when I put log4j.xml file right in tomcat/bin dir - everything works perfect. 
How can I point my IDE or project (dunno what exactly is pointing wrong) to the root of the project and not to tomcat/bin?

I appreciate every answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
Just put your log4j.xml in the root of /resources/ and apply the following lines to your pom.xml

```
<src.main.dir>src/main</src.main.dir>
<main.resources.dir>${src.main.dir}/resources</main.resources.dir>
```